# Javascript Local vs Global

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables

I thought I had this mess sorted out in my head but for some odd reason its not working.

If you declare a variable outside of a function / scope and refer to it without the var inside a function then it changes the variable declared previously... right?

however, the first alert returns the correct price, but the second (last) alert returns 0. What am I doing wrong?

```
//get pricing
var price=0;
var modelid = $("#model_input").val();
var inCode = $("#code_input").val();
$.get("getpricing.php", {  'modelid': modelid ,'code' : inCode }, function(data){
    price = data;
    alert(price);
});
alert(price);
```

Comment: Are you defining a price variable within the function fed to $.get?

Comment: @meder: the callback function is right there in the code... no there is no extra declaration

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using an **A**jax request.

Those, unkess specified otherwise, are **A**synchrounous : they are executed in the background, without stopping the execution of the rest of the script.

So, the `alert` on the last line of code is executed before the Ajax request is finished ; which means `price` is still 0 at that time.

One way to change that would be to use a synchronous request (see [async option](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options)) ; but I strongly advise against it ; quoting the doc :

> By default, all requests are sent
>   asynchronous (i.e. this is set to true
>   by default). If you need synchronous
>   requests, set this option to false.
>   Note that synchronous requests may
>   temporarily lock the browser,
>   disabling any actions while the
>   request is active.

And you definitly don't want your application to freeze the whole browser!

You should re-think the way your application is designed, in this case : you can only use the "price" information after the Ajax request is finished -- which probably means you should place more code inside the function called on its success : just placing code after the `$.get` is not enough.

Answer (score 3):

httprequests using .get are asynchronous, so the first alert (the second declared) will alert the original value as the callback for the request has not triggered yet.

Comment: Weird. I'm not actually using the price variable until an If and a For loop later (basically a ton of lines down). But by then, it still hasn't made the call I assume. If I just change to post will it work as expected?

Comment: No. post and gets are still asynchronous